# create values for column in pandas dataframe only for rows containing certain elements of a column

Tags: pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':['a','a','b','b'], 'y':[1,2,3,4]})
```

How can I create a column `z` which elements are equal to `y*2` but only for `a` elements in column `x`?

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
   x  y  z
0  a  1  2
1  a  2  4
2  b  3  na
3  b  4  na
```

Comment: You can do: `df['z'] = df.loc[df['x'] == 'a']['y'] * 2`

Comment: ```df["z"] = np.where(df.x.eq("a"), df.y.mul(2), np.nan)```

Comment: @mechanical_meat, nice answer. However, to avoid settingwithcopywarning, I would suggest nesting the ```y``` column within the ```loc``` bracket  -- > ```df['z'] = df.loc[df['x'] == 'a', 'y]* 2```

Comment: Oh, thanks! On the version I'm using that error isn't generated so I appreciate the notification.

Answer (score 0):

```
#using list comprehension with if else statements
df['z']=[y*2 if x=='a' else 'na' for x,y in zip(df['x'],df['y']) ]
```